# JS Promises implementation inside a funtion

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```js
    var test = function(){/*code here; return true;*/};
    var test1 = new Promise(
     function(resolve){
      var result = test();
      resolve(result)
     }
    )
    
    test1.then(function(result){/*code that use result*/});
```

I don't get the return value of test() here. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: **please note: I have used the test() function inside the test1 promise.
thanks for your kind help in advance.

Comment: Please show us your actual code and the expected output. And use `console.log(result)` to ensure that you are actually getting any return value.

Comment: Why are you using promises at all here if `test` is synchronous? If it is asynchronous (and doesn't `return` anything), you should use the `new Promise` *inside* `test` (not in `test1` only).

Comment: Btw, you don't need to comment to add details to your post, you can simply [edit] it

Comment: Your code looks fine as it is. tried on my browser works fine.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't really make any sense.  Why not just Promise.resolve(test())? Why are you creating a new Promise constructor for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code with actual return values in a working snippet.

```js
var test = function() {
  return 42;
};

var test1 = new Promise(
  function(resolve) {
    var result = test();
    resolve(result);
  }
);

test1.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```